# Maximise sum, Number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've got 4 positive integers, a,b,c,d which sum up to 63. The question asks for the maximum value of ab+bc+cd, but I don't get how to do it. I can't find an algebraic method, I can only use trial and improvement. Is there any better method I can use?

[This is a clarification of my previous question.]

Comment: This is a duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3251523/362009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suppose that the numbers are non-negative.

The sum can be rewritten as $ab+(63-a-c)c$. Since it does not contain $d$, we can assume $d=0$. Then $63-a-c=b$. So the sum is $ab+bc=b(63-b)=63b-b^2$. This parabola takes its maximum at $b=63/2$. So we need to check $b=31$ and $b=32$. In both cases the value is $32*31=992$. So the maximal value is $992$.

If you assume that the values are positive integers, you cannot take $d=0$, you should instead assume that $d=1$. Then the sum is $ab+bc+cd=ab+bc+c=b(a+c)+c=b(62-b)+c$ which does not depend on $a$. So we can assume that $a=1$, $c=61-b$. And the sum is
$b(62-b)+61-b=-b^2+61b+61$. The maximum of that parabola is at $b=61/2$, integer values $b=30$ and $31$ need to be checked. If $b=30$, the value is  $30*32+31=991$ and if $b=31$, the value is $31*31+30=991$. So the maximal value is $991$.

Comment: $d$ cannot be $0$. It is stated $4$ positive integers.

Comment: I have fixed that already. See the second part of the answer.

Comment: When $(a,b,c,d)=(1,30,31,1)$ we have maximum$=991$ so there must still be some problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I will fix it.

Comment: It is fixed. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let the variables be reals that sum to $63$.  Use the sum to replace one of them in terms of the others, then take the derivative of your objective with respect to the remaining ones.  That derivative must be $0$ at the maximum.  If the values at the maximum are not integers you need to hunt around, but you have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

$$ab+bc+cd=(a+c)(b+d)-ad$$

Note that $$(a+c)(b+d)\leq31\cdot32$$ and $$ad\geq 1$$

Both equalities are achievable by letting $$a=d=1,c=30,b=31$$